# Salesforce to Salesforce Multi-level child records

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have a parent record that has a child record, and that child record has a child record, and when I publish the parent record I want all the records down the heirarchy to be published to the target org. But when I do S2S it only pulls in the parent record and the first child record.

Is there a way I can pull in the further children records? I'm assuming I'll have to write some apex that publishes the parent, then the child then the child's child but do it in an order so I can still tie them all together from a trigger on the target instance?

Answer (score 0):

[AutoRABIT Dataloader](http://www.autorabit.com/salesforce-dataloader-pro/) is a very good choice for your need as it can perform dataloads of multi-level parent and multi-level children of an object effortlessly breaking any circular references and handling look-up/ self reference / master-detail relationships.

Pls. note:
I work as a customer success architect at AutoRABIT.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA